# Change user-agent in angular universal render

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, universal

How can I change the user agent?

I want all requests made by the application to the API when it is SSR (`response.render`) to be sent with a specific user agent.
currently sending something like

```
"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux x64) node.js/16.16.0 v8/9.4.146.24-node.21"
```

Comment: Careful. In some cases (as with mine) your live environment jams when sending webrequests during SSR

Comment: that's exactly what I want to protect myself from. What steps did you take to resolve the issue?

Comment: My angular app is hosted through asp.net core. We have the facility to [register](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices/blob/master/Demo/Demo.Web/Startup.cs#L43) a service with a [hook where we can pass data to the frontend](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.AspNetCore.SpaServices/blob/master/Demo/Demo.Web/Services/DemoSpaPrerenderingService.cs#L40). So no webrequests need to be sent during SSR, and on a Plesk live environment the website won't get stuck. The repository contains a demo application with all set up

Answer (score 2):

You can set the user agent header in your interceptor file, here's an example:

```js
//interceptor file
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserAgentInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const modifiedReq = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        'user-agent': 'Your Custom User Agent Here',
      },
    });

    return next.handle(modifiedReq);
  }
}
```

Comment: this option will also work. as I need to check if it is SSR (isPlatformServer) before setting headers.